# Can't set up config.py in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to set up `config.py` for using `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET`. This is not an error when these environments variable in `def xxxx()`. Then it is used as `current_app.config('XXXX')` but this can't be called outside `def xxxx()`.

Error:

> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
>   to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
>   this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
>   documentation for more information.

**auth.py**

```py
import functools
import pdb
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, current_app
)
import slack
from app.db import (
    get_or_create_team, get_or_create_user, get_or_create_team_user
)
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, LoginManager

bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')
client_id = current_app.config['CLIENT_ID']
client_secret = current_app.config['CLIENT_SECRET']
```

**config.py**

```py
# client
CLIENT_ID='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_SECRET='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: Can you clarify your explanation? Have you tried what the error message suggests? Also, I don’t think that’s the entire error.

Answer (score 0):

from:

```py
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, current_app
)

client_id = current_app.config['CLIENT_ID']
client_secret = current_app.config['CLIENT_SECRET']
```

to:

```py
from os import environ

client_id = environ.get('CLIENT_ID')
client_secret = environ.get('CLIENT_SECRET')
```